# Vlookup with VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to do an automated vlookupfunction but I am getting a run time error:

```
1004 "Unable to get the Vlookup property of the worksheet functionclass"
```

Would need some help on where it could have gone wrong and how it could be adjusted!

This is the code:

```
Sub FINDSAL()
'On Error GoTo MyErrorHandler:
Dim Seat_No As String
Seat_No = InputBox("Enter the Seat Number:")
If Len(Seat_No) > 0 Then
  nameit = Application.WorksheetFunction.Vlookup(Seat_No, Sheets("L12 - Data Sheet").Range("B4:E250"), 2, False)
  MsgBox "The name is : $ " & nameit
Else
  MsgBox ("You entered an invalid value")
End If
Exit Sub
MyErrorHandler:
If Err.Number = 1004 Then
  MsgBox "Employee Not Present in the table."
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Error 1004 usually means that VLOOKUP returns #NA. Have you tried un-commenting this line: 'On Error GoTo MyErrorHandler:

Comment: yes i did and it says employee not present but it does exist in the data sheet:/ @bioschaf

Comment: And to add to @bioschaf, my guess is that `Seat_No` is a string, but the seat number in your sheet is an integer, try `Application.WorksheetFunction.Vlookup(Int(Seat_No), ...`. More generally, set a break point at the VLookup and look what happens.

Comment: Okay got it! Thanks alot @stephan

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub FINDSAL()

On Error GoTo MyErrorHandler:
Dim Seat_No As Integer
Seat_No = InputBox("Enter the Seat Number:")
If Len(Seat_No) > 0 Then
  nameit = Application.WorksheetFunction.Vlookup(Seat_No, Sheets("L12 - Data Sheet").Range("B4:E250"), 2, False)
  MsgBox "The name is : $ " & nameit
Else
  MsgBox ("You entered an invalid value")
End If
Exit Sub
MyErrorHandler:
If Err.Number = 1004 Then
  MsgBox "Employee Not Present in the table."
End If
End Sub
```